# rewrite active voice to active voice, or passive to passive?

Tags: tenses, passive-voice, active-voice

Is it possible to rewrite a sentence and retain the same 'voice'?
We've been looking at active and passive voice in class, and how to rewrite from one to the other - but no one has mentioned Av to Av, or PV to PV, only Av to PV or PV to Av.

I don't think it's possible with simple sentences.  But is it possible to do so with larger, more complex sentences, or is it simply not doable?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're asking. Of course you can reword a sentence in active voice to another sentence still in active voice: from *They bought new clothes after school* to *After school they bought new clothes*. Can you provide an example of what you do or don't think is possible?

Comment: It's unclear what you find not clear.  The title is fairly concise, and the initial sentence is pretty much as clear as can possibly be!  Further, the second part of your comment kind of shows a pretty clear understanding of what was being asked.  Antagonisms aside, thank you for the comment and the example.

Comment: @choster - Or you can rewrite "I went home" to "Elephants stampede wildly across the African plain".  If all you need to keep the same is the voice, active or passive.

Comment: Hardly inline with the term "rewrite", which is usually construed as utilising the existing words in the existing sentence, whilst retaining the same semantic meaning.  But hey, if you want to show yourself up, go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's more than possible to rewrite a sentence which is in the active or passive voice and reword the sentence so that it remains active or passive. It's called syntax!

As choster, above, pointed out, simply re-arranging words and keeping the voice either active or passive is relatively easy to do. Moreover, it is a good idea to do just that, if only to keep you from developing a habit of wording your sentences in the same way all the time.

A couple examples of each:

***Passive to Passive***

> - The patient's fever was brought down by the doctors before any further damage could occur.
> - Before the fever could do any further damage, it was brought down by the doctors.

***Active to Active***

> - The receiver intercepted the pass at just the right time and scored a touchdown.
> - At just the right time, the receiver intercepted a pass and scored a touchdown.

That sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Those are complex sentences, yes?  In the second example, we are basically shifting the dependant part around, yes?   The first example seems more complex, omitting part, shifting parts, much more impressive.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @johnny98: You're welcome. The first two of my sentences are complex sentences; the second two are compound sentences. See this web site:  http://eslbee.com/sentences.htm    Don